# Unable to access the object properties returned from firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is probably a noob question as I couldn't find any similar questions here in stackoverflow. I am writing an ionic-angularjs application with firebase as the backend. I've a data snapshot returned by firebase snapshot.val() method and this is how the data shows up in my chrome console(attached pic)

```
var tmp = {};
CurrUser.getEventdesc(eventid).then(function (result) {
tmp = result;
console.log(tmp.Description);
});
```

CurrUser is a factory and getEventdesc is a function in the factory. The getEventdesc function looks like below:

```
getEventdesc: function(id) {
var deferred = $q.defer();
ref.child('Events').orderByChild('Eventid').equalTo(id).on('value', function (snapshot) {
event = snapshot.val();
console.log(event);
deferred.resolve(event);
});
return deferred.promise;
}
```

[image]

Now I'm trying to access the 'Description' property by tmp.Description in my angularjs controller but i get an 'undefined' error. I would be grateful if anyone could help me to access the object properties. Thanks for your time.

Update 2:

```
var tmp = {};
var newtemp = {}; 
CurrUser.getEventdesc(eventid).then(function (result) { 
tmp = result;
for (var itemID in tmp) { 
newtmp = tmp[itemID]; 
}; 
console.log(newtmp.Description); 
});
```

Regards,

Comment: Please post the code where you want to access the property, and the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're retuning the whole firebase object, not just the requested id, try this:

```
event = snapshot.val();
deferred.resolve(event[id]);
```

Comment: Thanks @Martijn Welker This is how my code looks now and am able to access the object property. Do you think this is the right approach? Thanks again.

    `var tmp = {};
    var newtemp = {};
    CurrUser.getEventdesc(eventid).then(function (result) {
    tmp = result;
    for (var itemID in tmp) {
    newtmp = tmp[itemID];
    };
    console.log(newtmp.Description);
    });`

Comment: @AjRev I've updated my code, please take a look at it

Comment: Thanks @Martijn. Infact, I need the entire object and use the other properties in the controller. Would be grateful if you could review the code that i posted in reply to your comment. For some reason, I am unable to indent the code properly. I assigned a new object 'newtmp' in the for loop and then access the property by newtmp.Description. I am not sure if this is the right approach. Thanks again.

Comment: @AjRev Could you post the properly formatted code as a new question, comment's shouldn't be used as chat

Comment: Sorry about that. Could you pls check update 2 in the original question? Thanks.